# Devolver nombre en vez de id Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo una tabla Coches y otra Marcas.

Mi tabla Marca es `(id, nombre)`

Mi tabla Coche es `(id, id_marca, modelo, color)`

Quiero que en la lista en vez de mostrarme el `id_marca`, me muestre el nombre de la marca.

Las relaciones ahora mismo las tengo así:

```
public function Coche() {
    return $this->hasMany(Coche::class);
}
```

```
public function Marca() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Marca::class, 'id', 'id');
}
```

He visto que puedo relacionar tablas con el `with::`, pero llevo poco tiempo con este framework y haber si me podéis ayudar.

Comment: Nos muestras la consulta que has intentado?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Leistes la documentacion? Ahi te explica que es https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: utiliza esta estructura donde pienses mostar el dato del nombre de la marca {{ $coche->Marca->nombre}}